# Angularjs function call issue with nested elements

Tags: angularjs, nested

I have an angulars setup as follows, trying to mimic some excel functionality where I have a controller nested inside an ng-repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="lw in lw_list"   my-lw   ng-model="lw" 
<td>
        <!-- next two elements act as an excel cell, one for inputing data, they other for displaying calcualtion result -->
        <div ng-controller="MyCellCtrl">
            <input type="text" class="inputdiv" ng-model="lw.library.name"   >in</input>                        
            <div  class="output"   ng-bind="getCellValue(lw.library.name)" syle="postion:absolute" contenteditable="True" >out</div> 
        </div>


        <div ng-controller="MyCellCtrl">
           more input / div pairs to act as a new cell      
           .....
        </div>

</td>
```

I have the stylesheets set up so that input and output are in the same position, and get hidden / unhidden, so that they act like an excel cell (you type a formula, then when you leave focus, it updates the content).

Anyway, when I put a console.log() inside the getCellValue() function, to show what instance of the controller is being called, then typing in one particular cell, I can see that getCellValue() is being called on every cell.

Is there some way to call getCellValue() when the input is updated without calling the method on every instance?

(I based this code on the code from this tutorial: 
https://github.com/graunked/spreadsheet
you can see the same behaviour by putting a console.log in the compute function. If you increase the arrays to 20 x 20 elements, it starts to get slow when you type anything.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to call getCellValue() when the input is updated without calling the method on every instance?

```
<div class="output" ng-bind="foo">
```

then use `$watch`:

```
function MyCellCtrl($scope) 
  {
  $scope.foo = $scope.lw.library.name;

  $scope.$watch('foo', function(newValue) {
    $scope.foo = getCellValue($scope.foo);
    });
  }
```

or use `viewChangeListeners` as an alternative:

```
function MyCellCtrl($scope) 
  {
  $scope.foo = $scope.lw.library.name;

  this.$viewChangeListeners.push(function(newValue) {
    $scope.foo = getCellValue($scope.foo);
    });
  }
```

**References**

- [Effective Strategies for avoiding watches in AngularJS](http://www.accelebrate.com/blog/effective-strategies-avoiding-watches-angularjs/)
- [Compile, Pre, and Post Linking in AngularJS](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx)